# Android app to call automatically using a pre recorded wav file

Tags: android, android-intent

We need to build a functionality in our Android app where we want to call to multiple mobiles with a pre recorded audio file present in the source device. We are not sure how to achieve this. One way is to play that wav file once the call is connected, but that wont be very clear to the end user.

Comment: Although I would agree that this is not supported in the Android SDK, I wouldn't say there isn't a way to do it. You would probably just have to go more native and interface directly with the buffer for the microphone (or whatever). I would think someone fairly well versed in AOSP and C (also the hardware drivers being used) would be able to help with this but it also requires root access, meaning not the type of app you could easily distribute through the play store.

Comment: thanks Jackie for your suggestion.

Comment: We are fine rooting the app as it is going to be used on some specific devices only and not on play store.

Comment: Again this would require extremely specific hardware (support OpenES) but this might help... http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/android-audio-streaming-with-opensl-es-and-the-ndk/

Comment: Also "Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_startRecording. 
For recording an ongoing stream, modify bqRecorderCallback to do 
another Enqueue of an empty buffer." https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/HZIlepVfMio

Answer (score 0):

Piping audio into the call stream is not supported by Android APIs. You can play it through the speaker while a call is ongoing, but that's about it. As you said, though, it won't be very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can play back the audio data only to the standard output device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during a call.

[official link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)